# Show Covergence, Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^x}{x^6+x} dx$$

This how i approached the problem:

1st Step : Using partial fractions.
$$e^x = A(x^5+1)+Bx^2+Cx$$

Now can i solve for $$Cx = e^x$$ and get $$C=e^{-ln(x)+x}$$

I want to understand if these are special kind of problem while, i dont think $$x^6+x)$$ is a polynomial that i could just factor. If someone has time and Energy to show me how it is done. Would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Can i show convergence of it easily without calculating all the bits?

Comment: $C=e^{x-\ln(x)}$, not $e^{\ln(x)-x}$

Comment: It's not useful to do integration by parts when the numerator is $e^x$.

Comment: the integral is not convergent

Comment: In a neighborhood of $0$ the integrand behaves like ${1\over x}\notin L^1(0,\varepsilon)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{e^{x}}{x^{6}+x}\geq \frac{1}{x^{6}+x}\geq \frac{1}{2x}$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$

Since the integrand is non-negative on $[0,1]$, the integral diverges by simple comparison with $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dx}{2x}}$$

Comment: Is that all i have to show to say it converges?

Comment: Well, the argument actually shows quite the opposite. Your integral diverges

Comment: ok sorry i meant diverges, how about showing it with an upper bound and a lower bound how would that fit in here? Using Riemann.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an argument by partial fractions. We can write:

$$\frac{e^x}{x^6+x} = \frac{-x^4e^x}{x^5+1} +\frac{e^x-1}{x} + \frac{1}{x}$$

The first term on the right side is continuous and hence integrable on $[0,1]$. The second term can be made continuous by defining it as $1$ at $x=0$ and hence is also integrable on $[0,1]$.

Thus $$\int_0^1 \frac{e^x}{x^6+x}\,dx$$ converges if and only if $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}$$ converges. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that for all real $x$ : $$e^{x}\geq x+1$$